How reading from pre-sorted plan node can return less rows than from index scan in top-n query in postgresql?
I was optimizing a query and encountered this strange query execution behaviour.
Query:
select active_preleads.id
from active_preleads
left outer join personal_scores 
  on active_preleads.id = personal_scores.prelead_id
where active_preleads."group" = 'personal'
  and active_preleads.time_zone >= 0
  and active_preleads.time_zone <= 6
  and active_preleads.base_name = 'reserve.dljaegrjul'
  and personal_scores.user_login = 'sales33'
  and active_preleads.assigned_user = 'sales33'
order by case when (active_preleads.region in ('RU-MOS', 'RU-MOW', 'RU-SPE')) then 0 else 1 end
       , personal_scores.score desc nulls last
limit 10;

Postgres version 14.12
Here are two different plans for this query after tuning the statistics for better row estimation by the query planner.
Before:

Raw explain analyze
After:

Raw explain analyze
My question is:
How is it possible that the gather merge node in the second plan yields only a small subset of rows, assuming that I ask for top-10 rows based on some order by and no index provides that order?
This is how I think it should work:

Read all rows because we can't know in advance that top-n rows will be in some subset.
Use top-n sort to retrieve the required rows.

I have tried to find information about this behavior but haven't found anything in the PostgreSQL documentation.
